# FAILED: S3Exception org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: ResponseCode=403, ResponseMessage=Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive

While trying to access a file from S3 under Hive, fails for access issue. What's the resolution?

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 's3n://[Bucket_Name]/FileName.csv' INTO TABLE table_name;
```

Access Key/Secret Key is already set under Hive console.

Comment: The secret key has "/" as part of key.

Comment: This is how it's set under HIVE. fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId='ABCDEFGHIJKHMNOPQR'
fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey='/ABCDEFGHIJKLMN'